# wp_redirect goes to infinity loop

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to check for logged-in users & redirects to pages with wp_redirect, but it goes through redirected many times

I have tried with template_redirect & init hooks

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {

if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_redirect( 'http://localhost/lawyer_portal/login/' );
    exit;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the follows code snippet -

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_specific_page' );

function redirect_to_specific_page() {
    // Assume that url login slug is a page
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_page( 'login' ) ) { 
        wp_redirect( 'http://localhost/lawyer_portal/login/' );
        exit;
    }
}
```